# Password bcrypt not working laravel 5.3

Tags: php, passwords, bcrypt, laravel-5.3

When i create a form password bcrypt working well but when i am going to edit and update password field it saves in simple text in database . Please help how to fix it.
**Store Function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $mydata['name']                    = $request->input('name');
    $mydata['username']                = $request->input('username');
    $mydata['password']                = bcrypt($request->input('password'));

     $data = Data::create($mydata);


      session()->flash('msg', 'User successfully created');
     return redirect()->route('home.index');
}
```

**Update Function**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $data = Data::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $data->fill($input)->save();
    session()->flash('msg',trans('User successfully Updated.'));
    return redirect()->route('home.index');
}
```

I am using same form for create and update. create is working well but when i edit form and update the password saves in simple text how to bcrypt it before save.
Please help i have defined update function above

Comment: You are directly accessing the password field and saving it into the db without hashing it. Hash it first and then save.

Comment: How to hash it ? @KinshukLahiri

Comment: similar to your `store` function ... `$mydata['password'] = bcrypt($request->input('password'));`

Comment: yes i have try but then how to pass '$mydata' to save function @S.l

Comment: You can request and take password which is inserted on the form like `$pass = Request::input('pass');`(or whatever is input name)

Comment: Please check documentation about password update and hash: https://laravel.com/docs/master/hashing